# How to change Text and Icon color depends on Background Image?

Tags: flutter

> Anyone knows how to change icon and text color depending on the background color of the image or video?

Answer (score 0):

The [palette_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator) package can help you find the most dominant color(s) in the image. You can use these color(s) to set the Text and Icon color.

[image: Color Palette Generator Demo]

Please check out the example code provided by the package author https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator/example . The PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider method can be used to get the color pallet from the image. You can use the following code from the example :

```
  Future<void> _updatePaletteGenerator(Rect newRegion) async {
    paletteGenerator = await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
      widget.image,
      size: widget.imageSize,
      region: newRegion,
      maximumColorCount: 20,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

....
  Color dominantColor = paletteGenerator.dominantColor?.color;
....
```

Please see the entire working code below : (Add palette_generator: ^0.2.3 to your pubspec.yaml first)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:palette_generator/palette_generator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Palette Generator',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future _updateColors;
  final List<PaletteColor> _colors = [];
  int _currentIndex;
  final List<String> _images = [
    'https://picsum.photos/id/491/200/300',
    'https://picsum.photos/id/400/200/300',
    'https://picsum.photos/id/281/200/300'
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentIndex = 0;
    _updateColors = _updatePalettes();
  }

  Future<bool> _updatePalettes() async {
    for (final String image in _images) {
      final PaletteGenerator generator =
          await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(NetworkImage(image));
      _colors.add(generator.dominantColor != null
          ? generator.dominantColor
          : PaletteColor(Colors.blue, 2));
    }
    setState(() {});
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Color Palette Generator Demo'),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: _colors.isNotEmpty
            ? _colors[_currentIndex].color
            : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: _updateColors,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == true)
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200,
                  color: _colors.isNotEmpty
                      ? _colors[_currentIndex].color
                      : Colors.white,
                  child: PageView(
                    onPageChanged: (value) =>
                        setState(() => _currentIndex = value),
                    children: _images
                        .map((image) => Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(image),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: _colors.isNotEmpty
                            ? _colors[_currentIndex].color
                            : Colors.white),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Color Palette",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: _colors.isNotEmpty
                                ? _colors[_currentIndex].titleTextColor
                                : Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 30.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.ac_unit,
                          size: 100,
                          color: _colors.isNotEmpty
                              ? _colors[_currentIndex].bodyTextColor
                              : Colors.black,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will check it out. .after that  I will upvote your answer

Comment: I have updated my answer and added the complete working code along with the screen recording. Just add palette_generator: ^0.2.3 to your pubspec.yaml file and run the code. Please up-vote and accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.